# Inserting multiple selected dropdown values into a single column

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Iam having a form which contaings of name,id etc..in this form iam getting dropdown from the same table only some ids here iam selecting multiple values and that should be inserted into db but only one value is inserting into the table remaining is not inserting can any one help me regarding this.

Model:

```
$data=array(
    'first_name'=>$this->input->post('first_name'),
    'exam_id'=>$this->input->post('exam_id'),
    );

$this->db->insert('table',$data);
```

This is my dropdown

```
$this->table = 'table';
$exam = $this->dropdown('exam_id','examr_id');
return $exam;
```

This is my view:

```
$exam['']='--Select --';
$exam_id="id='exam_id' ";
if($this->input->post('exam_id')) $selected=$this->input->post('exam_id');else $selected='';
echo form_multiselect('exam_id',$exam,$selected,$exam_id);?>
```

any one help me it will be more helpfull for me

Answer (score 0):

When you select multiple values and check that selected value pass in your url using GET or POST method. And than split your requested data using  [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function. and save into database.

Comment: Ha i used implode function then it is not inserting anything just inserting commas